# Core data group depending on attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am driving a table of person entities.

A Person entity might have a boolean attribute, that for the sake of this question I will call "group".

A Person entity also has a unique identifier in the system (Int64). The user case is that on the app a Person can be added multiple times to an arbitrary list, but, if that exact Person (by id) object is found 4 times (for example) in the list and the boolean group == true, I want the table to show only one cell for that Person.

```
Person:
  identifier:Int64
  group:Bool [if true, do show only one cell for Persons with that identifier and show a count]
```

I am wondering if there's a way to build a predicate that would allow me to show only one cell for persons that have the group == true.

That would allow me to show something like the image shown here below. 
Any person entity that is in the list multiple time but has group == true will show up only once (one cell) and show a count on that cell.

How could I accomplish this in Core Data? Is it just a predicate to figure out?

I'm thinking I might have to use `NSExpression`, but, I am not sure how to get this done yet.

Is the right question this then??:
`load all Persons and group those that have group == true by its identifier`

[image]

I tried this:

`load all Persons but group only those that have group == 1 by its identifier`

```
    let fr = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName:"Person")
    fr.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

    fr.propertiesToGroupBy = ["identifier"]
    fr.propertiesToFetch = ["identifier"]

    do {
        let persons = try ctx.fetch(fr)
        print("persons: \(persons)")

    } catch {

    }
```

Log:

```
persons: [{
    identifier = 1;
}, {
    identifier = 2;
}]
```

So, I don't know how to apply the 'group only' entities that have group == true...

Comment: The group flag makes it more complicated, should the count be included?

Comment: Will you ever have objects with the same name, some of which have group = true, and others have group = false?  And what order do you want the rows sorted?

Comment: I need the count yes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how close this will be to what you need, but I would try the following:

Replace your `group` boolean attribute with a `groupID` attribute.  If the object should be part of a group, set the `groupID` equal to the `identifier`.  If the object should not be grouped, leave the `groupID` as nil.

Use a fetchedResultsController to fetch the objects, using `groupID` to sort the objects and as the `sectionNameKeyPath` for the FRC.  The FRC will therefore create a section for each `groupID`, with the corresponding number of objects in the section (giving your count).  There will also be a section for those objects with `groupID` equal to nil, containing all those objects that should not be grouped.

In your tableView datasource methods, set the numberOfRowsInSection to 1 for all sections with a non-nil `groupID`, and for those sections use a cell to display the relevant name and the count of the number of items in the section.  For the section with nil `groupID`, set the numberOfRowsInSection to the count of items in the FRC section.  Create the rows in that section in the normal way.

Comment: makes sense. I didn't think about leveraging the section logic in an FRC to achieve what I needed. I'll report back once implemented. Thanks

Comment: So, this has a side effect in terms of making I will be constrained a bit on doing anything else with the sections.... but, it does seem to answer the question.